# Use css to apply global style to material.angular mat-card to set background color

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

Trying to change the background of material.angular.io mat-card globally.

I added the below to styles.css and it does not work.

```
mat-card {
  background:pink
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add a period in front of your css rule:

```
.mat-card {
    background: pink;
}
```

Here is a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v5yz8y-utpv95) to play with it using a forked example from the Angular Material site.

Comment: How do you know the 'mat-card' is a class or an element?

Comment: It's an Angular component directive which is provided by the angular material component library. In order to override the component directive styles you have to override the specified rule. In this case .mat-card as defined in the source code.

Comment: Play with the stackblitz. Change the `<mat-card>` to `<div class="mat-card">` You will find the css rule is still applied correctly.